# What is the use of CharArrayReader and StringReader?

Tags: java-io, java

I understand the other `Reader` subclasses in java.io, but I can't think of a use case where I'd need a `CharArrayReader` or a `StringReader` when I already have data available as `String` or `char[]`.

Is it because of compatibility? To "feed" a `String` or `char[]` into something that expects `Reader` as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not call it *compatibility*, it's *flexibility*.

You are right, some libraries that deal with character based data provide a method accepting a `Reader`. So the user of that library can choose any mechanism to feed that library.

If you have a file on the harddisk, use a `FileReader`. If you have an arbitrary `InputStream`, use an `InputStreamReader` (with an appropriate encoding). If you already have a simple `String` in your code, use a `StringReader`. And so on ...

Comment: I wouldn't call it *flexibility* so much as *abstraction* (which is closely tied with *encapsulation*).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been answered already, these classes are very handy when you write unit tests for a method that expects a reader.